# Dropping out the last rows in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, difference-between-rows

I have a data frame which could be approximated by the following example `df`:

```
a  <- seq(1, 1010, 1)
b  <- seq(2,1011,1)
c  <- c(rep(1,253), rep(2, 252), rep(3,254), rep(4,251))
d  <- c(rep(5,253), rep(6, 252), rep(7,254), rep(8,251))
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

Firstly I group my observations based on columns c and d. Then I want to have equal amount of observations (n=250) in each group. Basically, I want to remove the last rows of each group if they exceed the threshold of 250.

It is pretty easy to do with `if`, however it does take a plenty of time.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does something like this `df[ df$a < 250, ]` work?

Comment: I do not think so because it takes the rows in column a which is less than 250, but my question is about number of observations in each group grouped by column c and d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using package plyr:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(c, d), function(DF) head(DF, 250))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since speed seems to be an issue, you could use `dplyr` which is faster than `plyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
df %.% group_by(c,d) %.% mutate(count = 1:n()) %.% filter(count <= 250)
df$count <- NULL
```

Comment: @user3618375 happy to hear that :) by the way, i realized that you can probably write it this way: `df %.% group_by(c,d) %.% mutate(count = 1:n()) %.% filter(count <= 250) %.% select(-count)` so that you dont need the `df$count <- NULL`